# Angular Material : Material Navigation does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-schematics

I want to create a navigation schematics with this command :

```
ng generate @angular/material:navigation <component-name>
```

But it gives me an error as below :

**The 'path' option in '...\node_modules@angular\material\schematics\ng-generate\navigation\schema.json' is using deprecated behaviour.
'workingDirectory' smart default provider should be used instead.
(0 , validation_1.validateName) is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

Me too with a similar problem.

It may occur as a result of a version mismatch between the angular and the material.

Execute the following command to get a picture of the version mismatch.

```
ng update
```

If mismatched, update '@angular/material' using the following command.

```
ng update @angular/material@14
```

replace 14 with your angular version. That worked for me.